# Deserializing this XML Array with SimpleFramework

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I am trying to deserialize this XML Array with `SimpleFramework`, and I keep running into this issue:

> 07-04 16:14:59.840    1681-1681/com.sampleapp D/SampleApp﹕ org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'image' does not have a match in class com.todocodepathapp.api.models.Images at line 5

This is the xml array being returned from an API:

```
<response>
<data>
    <images>
        <image>
            <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lmdpfs0UcO1qbe5pxo1_1280.jpg</url>
            <id>9ik</id>
            <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=9ik</source_url>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6nl30dMm21qz59j6o1_1280.jpg</url>
            <id>MTU4NTM4NA</id>
            <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=MTU4NTM4NA</source_url>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m1e6655aqv1qz85pko1_500.jpg</url>
            <id>avd</id>
            <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=avd</source_url>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lz7cx55fOS1qbd47zo1_1280.jpg</url>
            <id>cu8</id>
            <source_url>http://thecatapi.com/?id=cu8</source_url>
        </image>
    </images>
</data>
</response>
```

And these are the model classes I am using (I have a hunch that I shouldn't be using **Images.java**, and there should only be three classes):

**Response.java**

```
@Root(name = "response")
public class Response {

    @Element(name = "data")
    private Data mData;
    public Data getData() {
    return mData;
    }

}
```

**Data.java**

```
@Root(name = "data")
public class Data {

    @Element(name = "images")
    private Images mImages;
    public Images getImages() {
        return mImages;
    }

}
```

**Images.java**

```
@Root(name = "images")
public class Images {

    @ElementList(entry = "image")
    private List<Image> mImageList;
    public List<Image> getImageList() {
        return mImageList;
    }

}
```

**Image.java**

```
@Root(name = "image")
public class Image {

    @Element(name = "url")
    private String mUrl;
    public String getUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    @Element(name = "id")
    private String mId;
    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    @Element(name = "source_url")
    public String mSourceUrl;
    public String getSourceUrl() {
        return mSourceUrl;
    }

}
```

How should I be accomplishing this? I thought that adding the annotation with the entry `@ElementList(entry = "image")` would solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch was correct, and I went ahead and deleted the class `Images.java` and added the following annotations to my `Data.java` model class:

```
@ElementList(name = "images", entry = "image")
private List<Image> mImages;
public List<Image> getImages() {
    return mImages;
}
```

One note is that I changed `@Root` to `@Element` for the Image model class:

```
@Element(name = "image")
public class Image {

    @Element(name = "url")
    private String mUrl;
    public String getUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    @Element(name = "id")
    private String mId;
    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    @Element(name = "source_url")
    public String mSourceUrl;
    public String getSourceUrl() {
        return mSourceUrl;
    }

}
```